# A world like an ice-cream sandwich?

Tags: geography, geology, nonspherical-worlds

Ice-cream sandwich is the only way to describe the world I am thinking of making. There's flat land above, flat land below and mountains all around. The light comes from stars that hover in the middle of it all. How could this work scientifically?

Here's a picture to explain what I mean:[image: Sandwich world]

Of course there's mountains and stuff on the land, I just simplified it to accommodate my artistic limits

Answer (score 5):

**Rotating Cylinder Habitat**

[image]

The world is on the inside of a rotating cylinder. The centrifugal force creates gravity against the inner surface. People on one side of the cylinder can see the other side above them.

It looks like a sandwich and not a cylinder because (a) the landscape is hilly, so you cannot the curve on your own section and (b) two slices -- each a quarter of the diameter -- are removed to separate the two halves of the sandwich.

The stars are not stars. They are artificial lights along the central axle of the cylinder. Maybe they are mirrors that reflect exterior stars. When it goes off for the night you can see some real stars through the slices in the cylinder.

Comment: Downvote for lack of ice cream.

Answer (score 0):

### Not possible naturally someone would have to build it

A potentially natural option. Binary planet system where 2 planets orbit a common center of gravity shared between them. The planets revolve on a shared axis, but one planet may spin faster than the other. The point between the two planets are under the effects of constant storms and is generally avoided. Otherwise the 2 planets function fairly normally to our own, with the occasional shadow darkening one or the other.

You could similarly have 2 hemispheres orbiting each other around a shared center of mass. How it would form would likely be astronomically unlikely chance (as it needs to develop life after the orbits were established) or constructed by some higher power. For stars to exist between these hemispheres, the hemispheres would need to be larger than stars. I'd suggest having an artificial light source, or perhaps magic/constructed artificial stars that can produce life giving heat and light without having to require large mass and size.

Impossible naturally, but a potential solution would be 2 fast spinning discs (the centrifugal "force" keeping the disc pulled flat) orbiting around a shared center of mass. Though you run into issues with the affects of gravity, wanting to pull you to the center of the disc more as you get toward the outside edge unless counter balanced by the spin.

Geological processes wouldn't function at all as they do on Earth, with exception to the outer edges of the formation (outside edge, rather than the interior mountains. This is because on Earth, the center of gravity is at it's core, pulling itself inward. In this binary system, the center of gravity is in open space between the two halves. Gravity would be enough to hold you to onto one half at a time, but the closer to the other half you get, the less weight you would appear to have, so someone living on the outside edge would feel like they weight much more than someone living on the interior mountains, despite having the same mass. It would be difficult to keep the two halves flat and preventing the outer edges from collapsing on themselves to become more round over time.

Any additional details may help in producing a better answer.

Comment: Artificial worlds are okay too.

Comment: I think you would be heavier living near the centre of one of the plates than near the edge.